# What is the flow of ionic loading css file？

Tags: ionic-framework

My Ionic's version is 3.9.2. I create a new project by using 
`ionic start myApp tabs`.

And I found that the scss file was not manually imported in every component, but the css style was loaded on the page. So, I had a question. how does ionic know which scss file corresponds to which component?

And I tried to find the answer in the document and found this sentence.

*Pages are meant to be loaded dynamically, they don’t need to have a selector. However, the selector is useful in order to override the default styles on a specific page (see hello-ionic.scss):*

I can't understand what this sentence means.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

besides the scss file specific to each page, ionic has a scss file that is in the app folder(src/app/app.scss). What is there, worth for all pages. When the file is page-specific, it means that whatever you use in that scss file, will be specific to the page it belongs to. In addition to these two places, in the structure of the ionic, there is a paste theme(src/theme), there is another scss file (variables.scss), which if you open, you will see that there are some standard colors of the system as well as other details. If you want to test, change the color of the "primary" variable, for example. You'll notice that your app's default color has changed.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, you're right. But my question is Every component has own scss file and needn't import like angular by using `styleUrl` Identifier. Hope you can answer for me.

Comment: Sorry man, my mistake, I got it wrong. The scss file of a page, actualy works bacause of its selector that you have on the scss. For example: I have a recipePage. In the recipe folder, I have the recipe.scss. Inside the scss file, if we note, have a selector like page-recipes {}. Inside of that selector, you put what you want, and it will work just for recipePage. If you take the selector down, it will become generic. I made myself understood?

Comment: I forgot one thing, the selector you get in the scss file, you specify on the .ts file of your page. @Component({selector: 'page-recipes'...})